# Dynamic Navbar links in the shared layout MVC/Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I would like links on the navigation bar to appear or disappear depending upon the data in the database. All the nav bar links are in _Layout.cshtml which is being used by all pages.

```
<ul>
 @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  {
   <li class="nav-item dropdown">
     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Bookings</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">                             
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("All Bookings", "GetAllBookings", "Booking")</li>
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Member's Dashboard", "GetBookingsByStatus", "Booking")</li>
     </ul>
   </li>                     
</ul>
```

I would like member's dashboard to only appear if they are a member and have certain attributes in their profile. What is the best way to dynamically changing the nav bar links depending upon the data in database?

Comment: instead of this User Authenticated check put your own customized check like whether the user has particular attributes or particular roles like that.

When the first requests gets created you can load those values and can check in the share view and render the view based on condition.

Comment: @RajeshB How do I check for site attributes, that is my whole question. This is a layout page which is used by every controller and layout page is not using any model so how will I get the data?

Comment: do you understand how to include conditional ifs on the layout page?  If not i'll post something that gives you a hint.

Comment: @JohnLord I know how to write If and else in razor view? I want to know how can I grab data in layout Page. For example: Member attributes are in table tblCustomer and this layout page does not use any model. Let me know if you want to see any code?

Comment: sorry about the delay.  work emergency.   So basically you MUST pass data to the page in order to act on data.  You have a couple of options.  One is to create a model for the page to use, but that's possibly not useful in this scenario.  You can also pass viewbag variables.  As far as i am aware, those are your only two options.  It couldn't hurt to post code and someone can do more for you.

Comment: @JohnLord Thank you John but I am changing my code to start using Roles so I can just check roles to remove the links. But upon checking roles are getting updated in view after signing out from the website? Do you know anything about that?

Comment: upon logout you will simply reload the page.  This will actually be necessary because the page is rendered at load.

Comment: @JohnLord but I do not want to logout them after their roles are changed. I am just returning a new view? Will I have to reload the page in a different way?
I tried reloading the page myself with ctrl + f5 but it still did not remove the links untill I logged out and logged back in

Comment: I misunderstood your question.  I thought you were saying you were logging them out on purpose.  The only thing i can think of is you aren't reloading the menu and are loading partial views into a frame.  The menu would have to be redrawn after a permission is changed.

Comment: @JohnLord How can I redraw the whole view after changing the role?

Comment: The only thing you can do is put permissions on each individual page's view function in the controller, and load the entire page when navigating instead of just replacing contents in a frame.

Comment: @JohnLord I do not think refreshing is the issue. The problem is with Asp.NET Identity you have to sign in user again with Identity functions

Answer (score 1):

even in your sample code, you can just leave out the list items by wrapping them in an @if conditional and checking their permissions in whatever method you see fit.

However, I hope I'm pointing out the obvious, but this method only hides the link.  It doesn't prevent the user from typing it in or using a bookmark.  You will also need to duplicate the security check in your controller.

Comment: How can this be possible, As I mentioned this is a layout page which is used by every controller. It is not using any model. How will it have controller/model data?
Can you share some sample code?

Comment: the layout page may not  use a controller, but the links surely do.  I'm saying you need to do permission checks on every page, not just on the main menu.  Redirect to your home page.  Something like this:    [Authorize(Roles = "viewOrders")]
        public ActionResult OrderList()
        {
(you can't code tag a comment)  This assumes you're using the roles in the database.  If not you can write your own function and check in the controller.   if (!CheckIfHasPermission(user))
                return RedirectToAction("MainMenu");

Comment: I do not want to redirect them to different pages, I am not using roles. I want links to not show up if they have certain attributes. Those action links are on shared layout page.

Comment: but you need to redirect them from inside the controller.  The controller MUST be secured or someone can just go to the link directly even if the button is gone.  If you are using roles now, you can check them with annotations on each function.